# Swift show alert if UIMenu Item is pressed

Tags: swift

Is there a way to show an alert window if a UIMenu item is selected? I need to be able to present the alert however I get error my function does not have member present

```
let menuActions = UIAction(title: "Create New Profile", image: nil, handler: { [self] (item) in
  
        // Create new Alert
        var dialogMessage = UIAlertController(title: "Confirm", message: "Are you sure you want to delete this?", preferredStyle: .alert)
        
        // Create OK button with action handler
        let ok = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: { (action) -> Void in
            print("Ok button tapped")
         })
        
        //Add OK button to a dialog message
        dialogMessage.addAction(ok)

        // Present Alert to
        self.present(dialogMessage, animated: true, completion: nil)
        })

let menu = UIMenu(title: "Profiles", children: [menuActions])

/// Adds the menu to the system
builder.insertSibling(menu, afterMenu: .application)
```

Comment: There does not seems to be an issue with the code as I have tested it on a button but it's not clear in your case what that "builder" is supposed to be. For me it's working fine and 'Confirm' popup is presenting. let me know so I can help

Comment: `self.present(dialogMessage, animated: true, completion: nil)` is a method of `UIViewController`. If the code you posted isn't in a `UIViewController` class then you can't call `present` on `self`.